# having trouble using methods that are not static

Tags: methods, constructor, instance, public

I have this method:

```
public Route getSubroute(int startOffset, int endOffset) {

    if (!(0 <= startOffset && startOffset < endOffset && endOffset <= this
            .getLength())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Subroute is out of bounds.");
    }
    // the sub-segments that will make up the sub-route
    List<Segment> subsegments = new ArrayList<>();
    // variable offset is the distance along the route to the start of the
    // segment currently being examined
    int offset = 0;
    for (Segment segment : segments) {
        if (startOffset - offset < segment.getLength()
                && 0 < endOffset - offset) {
            // part of the segment belongs on the sub-route
            int subsegmentStartOffset =
                    segment.getStartOffset()
                            + Math.max(startOffset - offset, 0);
            int subsegmentLength =
                    (Math.min(endOffset - offset, segment.getLength()) - 
                            Math.max(startOffset - offset, 0));
            subsegments.add(new Segment(segment.getSection(), segment
                    .getDepartingEndPoint(), subsegmentStartOffset,
                    subsegmentStartOffset + subsegmentLength));
        }
        offset += segment.getLength();
    }
    return new Route(subsegments);
}
```

when i try to make another method in a new class which calls this method i get an error:

1. Constructor Route in class Route cannot be appiled to given types;
2. required: List
3. Found: no arguments
4. Reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

My code is as follows and this error appears on the line [Route newRoute = new Route()]

```
public Route subRouteV(int startOffset, int endOffset){
        Route newRoute = new Route();
        Route vSubR = newRoute.getSubroute(startOffset, endOffset);
    }
```

Comment: The error says that the constructor of `Route` requires a List as argument.
This line `Route newRoute = new Route();` calls the constructor without any argument.
Can you provide the signature of the constructor of `Route` or check it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from that line
    `Route newRoute = new Route();`

You must either

1. Call the constructor of `Route` with an argument
2. Build a new constructor for `Route`that takes no arguments.